# Stack implementation by resizing the stack size

Tags: data-structures, dynamic, stack

I was trying to implement a stack using java with resizing stack size.
My code is right and it's running well but after popping the element from the stack when I call the peek function again the same element is showing on top of the stack.
Show what changes should I make to make my code correct.

```
class DynamicStack
{
private int stack[];
private int stackSize;
private int top ;

DynamicStack()
{
stackSize = 1;
top = -1;
stack = new int[stackSize];
}

public int isEmpty()
{
        if(top == -1)
        {
            System.out.println("Stack is empty");
        }
    return 0 ;
}

public int isFull()
{ 
    if(top == stackSize-1)  
    {
        System.out.println("Stack is full");
    }
        return 0;
    }

public int pop()
{
    return stack[top];
}

public void push(int data)
{
     if(top>=stackSize-1)
    resize();
    stack[++top]=data;          
}

private void resize()
{
int[] temp= stack;
stackSize = stackSize*2;
stack = new int[stackSize]; 

for(int i= 0;i<=top;i++)
{
stack[i]=temp[i];   
}
}

public int peek()
{
    return stack[top];
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    DynamicStack ds = new DynamicStack();

    ds.push(12);
    ds.push(13);
    ds.push(2); 
    System.out.println(ds.stackSize);
    System.out.println(ds.peek());
    System.out.println(ds.pop());
    System.out.println(ds.peek());      
    
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should update your `top` variable as you did while pushing to the stack.

```java
public int pop()
{

    return stack[top--];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much I forgot to decrement the top.